# Netlogo : how to make patches have the distance information from a certain red patch

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make all patches have distance information from the red point [5 -5]. And then these distance information will be used for opinion dynamics in the end.

```
 patches-own [e-distance]
```

i added e-distance to insert the distance information

```
to setup
   clear-all
   ask patch 5 -5 [
       set pcolor red
       ]    
 end

 to go 
   let red-patch patches with [ pcolor = red ]

 end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998359/how-can-i-compute-the-distance-between-two-patches

Comment: Thanks bergant, I checked the link,  but i am wondering how that distance information can be saved on "e-distance" on each patch

Answer (score 1):

Use `distance`:

```
ask patches [ set e-distance distance red-patch]
```

Before that make sure your `red-patch` is an agent (not agent set). Change your `let` with `one-of`:

```
let red-patch one-of patches with [ pcolor = red ]
```

Comment: Thanks alot!  It works well.  Specially thanks for the comment "Before that make sure your red-patch is an agent (not agent set). Change your let with one-of"